# Find top K scores for a day - Algorithmic question

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Im struggling with solving this question:

Given an array of queries ( Representing start, end date and scores you get in this interval) , and number of days, and the value "k". Find the highest score possible which can be achieved in a given day.

```
n = 10 # Number of Days
queries = [
    [1, 5, 300], # start, end, value
    [4, 8, 700],
    [6, 9, 100],
    [1, 2, 100],
    [2, 5, 200],
    [3, 4, 300]
]
```

So, on day 4, we will get the maximum score 1500 (300 + 700 + 200 + 300).
However, the question had constraint to take top k for a day.

k = 2 we can take 300 + 700 to maximize the score
k = 3 we can take 300 + 700 +300 to maximize the score

The linesweep algorithm is straightforward:

```py
n = 10 # Number of Days
queries = [
    [1, 5, 300], # start, end, value
    [4, 8, 700],
    [6, 9, 100],
    [1, 2, 100],
    [2, 5, 200],
    [3, 4, 300]
]
def sweepline(queries,num_days,k=0):

    n = num_days
    pfx_sum = [0 for _ in range(n+1)]
    
    for st,en,val in queries:
        pfx_sum[st-1] += val
        pfx_sum[en] -= val
    
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        pfx_sum[i] += pfx_sum[i-1]

    print(max(pfx_sum))
```

However this disregards the top "k" part, and sums up all the values to give values in an interval.
How do i allow for the top "k" values in the above?

Comment: To calculate the prefix sums (scores for each day). This gives you the total score, but not the top "k" score. One solution that came to mind was using heaps? (use a min heap at each index of the prefix array and pop the smallest when the size exceeds "k". But this will exceed the memory requirements i think.

Comment: That's bad design in terms of function responsibility. It should either return total sum for all days, or a sum for a specified day, or top `k` values for the specified day.

Comment: The focus is not on the design here, but on the correct approach for the problem.

Comment: Side note: It would have been an interesting problem if you would have to find the day with maximised score, made by k individual scores. It was what I first understood, but then noticed the day is an input, making it rather trivial.

Comment: Oh i think you are right. Assuming we have to maximize the score, considering only "k" possible individual scores, how would we approach that for all the days? I am also updating the question for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this:

```
# expand data to lists of values for given day
pfx_values = [[] for _ in range(n)]
for start, end, value in queries:
    for idx in range(start-1, end):
        pfx_values[idx].append(value)

# sum each day
pfx_sum = [sum(lst) for lst in pfx_values]

# sum k largest values for each day
k = 2
pfx_top = [sum(sorted(lst)[-k:]) for lst in pfx_values]
```

`range()` arguments may need adjustment depending on how your ranges are set up.

Comment: I think this works, but has a high time complexity - Is there something more optimal than this which comes to mind?

Comment: Which solution is best for you depends on what data you want and what you're doing with it. Also, keep in mind that stackoverflow answers are more for illustration rather than performance as they're meant for not just you, but also future readers.

Answer (score 0):

A quick generator expression will pull out the values you need. Then it's just a case of summing up the first `k` elements.

```py
day = 4
values = sorted((v for s, e, v in queries
                 if s <= day and e >= day), reverse=True)
print(values)
# [700, 300, 300, 200]

k = 2; print(values[:k], sum(values[:k]))
# [700, 300] 1000

k = 3; print(values[:k], sum(values[:k]))
# [700, 300, 300] 1300
```

Using `itertools` is a bit nicer if you want different `k`'s without re-summing the whole list:

```
import itertools

day = 4
values = sorted((v for s, e, v in queries
                 if s <= day and e >= day), reverse=True)
cumsum = list(itertools.accumulate(values))

k = 2; print(cumsum[k-1])
# 1000

k = 3; print(cumsum[k-1])
# 1300
```

Comment: Oh this is pretty smart. You are taking only taking the values which are required in the range and reverse sorting them to get the answer. @Ouroborus solution also works, but you have to iterate through each day and then sort ( If the number of queries are high) this can be O(Q * N) (Iterating queries) + O(N^2) ( Sum) + O(N^2 LogN). (Rough calculation)

Do you have any other optimization in mind?

Comment: You *might* get better performance with something like a fixed-size max heap to track the `k` largest values and avoiding the sort, but that incurs its own overhead that might actually be slower. The only way to truly understand performance is to measure.

Comment: I just realized, that i need to maximize without being given the actual day. Many apologies for the confusion. I need to consider top "k" values for each day and then return the maximum score possible amongst all days.